# Can you transform characters to uppercase in a drop down inside a grid column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid where I have column that has a autocomplete on it where a user enters letters for a part nbr search. (On a side note - I tried the Kendo autocomplete and could not get that going so went with the Jquery autocomplete instead)
This works fine, but would like to have when a user types, it transforms their lower case letters to uppercase.
Is this possible in jquery or do I have to use an event inside the grid.

I've tried different scenarios and none seem to work.  As you can see, I commented out what I tried.
I do have this code in other functions and this does work great, but cannot use it within a grid it seems.
`$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());`

```
//Dropdown Autocomplete Part Nbr within Kendo Grid...
function AutoSearchPartNbrGrid(container, options){
   var y = $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
   .appendTo(container)
   .autocomplete({
   minLength: 4,
   autoFocus: false,
   source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: String.format('{0}/{1}', $('#hfAutoCompletePartsApiUrl').val(), request.term.toUpperCase()),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
               response($.map(json, function (data, id) {
               return {label: data.label,value: data.value                                       }
               }));
              }
            });
                        },
        edit: function (e) {
              //$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase()); 
              //autopartnbr = $(this).val();

              //Search Fields to populate the parts grid...
              //$(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
              //    var txt = $(this);
              //    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
              //        if (txt.val() !== '') {
              //            autopartnbr = $(this).val();
              //        }
              //        return false;
              //    }
              //});

           //var grid = $('#divconfigs').data('kendoGrid');

           return false;
         },
         select: function (e, ui) {
                 autopartnbr = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

                 var grid = $('#divconfigs').data('kendoGrid');

                 return false;
         },
         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
                },
         failure: function (response) { alert(response.responseText) }
                });


   }
```

I expect that when you type a part nbr in and if you have a lowercase letter, it would automatically transform it to an uppercase.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to change the val. like just try `$(this).val("hello");` does that works?

Comment: I tried:     autopartnbr = $(this).val("hello").toUpperCase();

Comment: And it put 'hello' in the grid...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the purpose of such a transformation (lowercase to uppercase) is to compare it with your database entries. In this case, you could use the autocomplete-function and add a matcher-function to perform the transformation :

```
 <input type="text" name="query" id="query" value="" /> 
 <script>
var names=["MYUPPERCASE-ENTRY1","MYUPPERCASE-ENTRY2","MYUPPERCASE-ENTRY3"];
$( "#query" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
matcher=new RegExp("^"+ $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term ), "i" );         

response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
          value = value.label || value.value || value;    
          return matcher.test(value.toString().toUpperCase());
        }) );
      },
      minLength: 3
    });
 </script>
```

More info : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I put the matcher=new RexExp and response statements before the ajax call

Comment: var y = $('<input style="text-transform: uppercase;" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')

Comment: The above works, as putting the text-transform makes any characters change to uppercase.  Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Dear  SteveA , could you mark my answer to your issue as selected please ?